# Bash: splitting items from a definite column

Tags: bash, shell, cut

- I have a file of `tsv` format containing the line ->

  ```
  1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910   1   New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA  19,015,900  1   New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083
  ```
- It has 3 `tab` delimited columns. Which are ->

  `1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910`

  `1   New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA  19,015,900`

  `1   New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083`
- I want the first 4 `comma (',') seperated` elements of the `first column`, which is ->

  `1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910`
- ***My approach*** is `cut -d',' -f1-4` and in this case, my approach gives output like ->

  `1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910   1   New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island`

How can I fix this??

Original problem link : https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/text-processing-cut-5?h_r=next-challenge&h_v=zen

Comment: First `cut` first column using delimiter `\t` (`cut`default) and redirect it to second `cut` using ',' as delimiter and output first four cols, ie. `cut -f 1 file|cut -d \, -f 1-4`.

Comment: Have you tried using awk for this problem?

Comment: tab is default delimiter for cut.. ex: `echo -e '1\t2\t3\t4' | cut -f1`

Comment: Nope, `awk` doesn't work in my terminal, even after it's installed. @dood

Comment: @JamesBrown : That isn't still working as i have some more `tabs` in the file. :( Anyway, i'm interested about some terms in your comment which are new to me. Can you explain?? Probably an elaborate answer ??

Comment: It shouldn't matter. With `-f 1` you define which fields you want the first `cut`to send to the second one for further processing. Please post an example of a non-working line. Which _new terms_ are you talking about?

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. But, your appreach outputs just a  `1` for the case i've described above in my question. @JamesBrown

Comment: @JamesBrown: Leave it. I just found what the problem was! In the original `hackerrank` problem, there are some extra unnecessary `tabs`. I have fixed my problem now. THanks for your help :)

Comment: Correct answer is `cut -f 1-2 file|cut -d \, -f 1-4`. Am I right ?? @JamesBrown

Comment: Well, looking at the original question _print the first three fields_ `cut -f 1-3` should be enough.

Comment: Nice! You can post it as an answer and i'll accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cut -f-2`  <- The Answer of my question

`cut -f-3`  <- The answer to the HackerRank Problem, as it has some indentation problem

(I'm just splitting by the `tab` and taking the first two parts.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk to do this very simply:

```
echo -e "1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910\t1 New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA  19,015,900\t1   New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083" | awk -F '\t' ' { print $1 } '
```

Output:

```
1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910
```

Comment: there is no `\t` in my input. and this command isn't working for the right input.

Comment: @jbsu32 you wrote that you have 3 tab delimited columns, \t is simply converted to a tab when used with echo -e which enables interpretation of backslash escapes.

Comment: Well, you could simply answer `echo -e "1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910 1 New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA  19,015,900 1   New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083" | awk -F '\t' ' { print $1 } '`

Answer (score 0):

You want this?

```
cut -d $'\t' -f-3
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `cut -d $'\t' -f-3`??

Comment: Tab is the default delimiter for `cut`.  The `-f` option should definitely have a dash in front of it.  `cut -f-3` cuts fields 1-3.

Comment: I fix @jbsu32 tanks

Comment: Your comand do not work in the site described in Question @tripleee